# Transferring a big tar file using rsync on Linux

Tags: rsync, tar, archive, file-transfer

I need to transfer a .tar folder to a remote server and because it's very large I can't unpack it on my computer and then transfer it. 
I am using "rsync" but it doesn't work:

```
rsync -av  folder/folder/etc./name.tar.xz remote_server.ac.uk: folder/etc./

sending incremental file list
name.tar.xy
```

And it stops here... nothing more happens

Any suggestions?

Comment: How big is the file? How long did you wait? Maybe it takes a while to transfer the data.

Comment: Add the --progress or (newer) --info=progress2 flag.

Comment: Is the space after the `:` in what looks as the destination in the actual command that you used?  If not, then the file may just take a long time to transfer. Use `--progress` as Colin suggested to see the progress of the transfer.

Comment: "Folder" is the wrong term. It is a single file, being already a tar archive with subsequent compression. The -a (archive) option invokes about 7 other options that really are not applicable to a single file.